# MVC actionlink parameter access from resulting view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have my URL
`/Admin/EditUser/18094c7d-4013-4723-81d2-0f2a863341db?pwchange=True` which is got my passing parameters via an action link `new { id = ID, pwchange = true}` . How do i access the pwchange from the view?

I can do this in other web languages such as PHP with a simple _GET, in MVC however, i can't seem to find an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this in your controller -

```
var pwchange = Request.QueryString["pwchange"].ToString();
```

Then pass your value to the view via a view object or in the `ViewBag`